# HTML,Making site mobile-friendly,auto-redirect not working for all phones

Tags: html, .htaccess

CONTEXT:
I have an old site in HTML4.01 Transitional and made the following changes in order to satisfy GoogleBot's new rules for having viewport/mobile-friendly pages:

1. created subdomain 'm' for mobile viewable page versions.
2. added to .htaccess file:
   # Check for mime types commonly accepted by mobile devices
   RewriteCond....
3. On main desktop home page added some meta tags in 
   such as:

   if (screen.width < 574) {
    var ref = document.referrer;
    var urls = new Array(.....mobile url & main index page)

4. On subdomain /m pages, put in

   @media screen and (min-width:240px) and (max-width:480px), 
   screen and (min-device-width:240px) and (max-device-width:480px)
    {
        /* Styles */
   }
   /* mobile styles */
   @media handheld { ....

QUESTION:

While googlebot now tells me my site is 'mobile-friendly', when I check various phones through
emulators on my desktop PC they do not show the mobile page. In checking an Android, the auto-redirect goes to mobile page. On iPhone it does not.

What am I missing?

[I can't put links as this is my first use of stackoverflow so have no reputation rating, site used m. and www . yokodanaCOM

## Thankyou in advance.

ANSWER, May 3, 2015:

Following advice received I have solved this problem.
Here are steps taken:

1. added to .htaccess file of main www domain:

   RewriteEngine On
           # Check for mime types commonly accepted by mobile devices
           RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT}     "text/vnd.wap.wml|application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml" [NC]
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
           RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
2. Make all html pages web responsive by putting all content inside tables at 100%
3. Reduced size of logos & images.
4. Added following code inside  of all root www html files:

   if (screen.width < 800) {
            var ref = document.referrer;
            var urls = new Array("ht...exampledotcom","ht....m.exampledotcom");
            var n = ref.match(urls[0]);
            var m = ref.match(urls[1]);
            if ((m!==null) || (n!==null)) {
            stop;
            }
            else if (ref=='') {
            var r = confirm("Small Display is Detected.\nClick \"OK\" for MOBILE SITE.");
            if (r==true) {
             window.location = "ht....m.exampledotcom";
             }
             else {
             stop ;
            }
            }
            else
            {
            window.location = "ht....m.exampledotcom";
            } 
           }

   ```
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

       ....
       </HEAD>
   ```

   5. In mobile subdomain html pages (m.exampleDOTcom)added to inside :

screen.css and mobile.css are empty files

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="ht....m.exampleDOTcom/screen.css" type="text/css" media="Screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="h....m.exampleDOTcom/mobile.css" type="text/css" media="handheld" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />

    <style type="text/css">

@media screen and (min-width:240px) and (max-width:480px), 
   screen and (min-device-width:240px) and (max-device-width:480px)
{
     /* Styles */
}
/* mobile styles */
@media handheld {

    html, body {
        font: 12px/15px sans-serif;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 3px;
        color: #000;
        margin: 0;
        }
    #sidebar, #footer {
        display: none;
        }
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
        font-weight: normal;
        }
    #content img { 
        max-width: 250px;
        }
    .center {
        width: 100% !important;
        text-align: center;
        }
    a:link, a:visited {
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: #0000CC;
        }
    a:hover, a:active {
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: #660066;
        }

}
/* iPhone-specific styles */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { 

    html {
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
        }

}


</style>
```

===========

I thought I should at least share what worked for me in case someone else searches for same question. Glad to have discovered this site as I am an autodidact when it comes to coding and this site has integrity and is very helpful. I appreciate how well moderated it is. Thank you.

Comment: Not really an answer. But shouldn't you try Responsive webdesign instead of redirecting it? Just because google "likes" it doesn't  mean your customers will ...

Comment: @Danny van Holten : Thanks for taking a look at this. That is great advice and that's what I'm going to do. After struggling for  a few days with all manner of JS, meta, redirects, htaccess etc, it dawned on me that I had built this page maybe 5years ago and unlike stuff I've added to the site more recently, it is not at all 'mobile responsive'. So, I'm taking your advice, thanks for your time.

Comment: *Putting everything in a table with 100% width* is **not** the same as making your website responsive. Read up on some design guidelines for responsive websites. [This](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries) is a good start. It's probably more work to rework all your CSS, but at the end you'll be more satisfied *and* you are set for the future - whatever devices are introduced.

Comment: @BramVanroy:  Good advice. I realize what I have now is an imperfect solution and that I need to do some study on this. Appreciate your comment, tnx.

Answer (score 0):

I forget to add the IPHONE code:

```
<script language=javascript>
<!--
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) ||   
(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
location.replace("http://url-to-send-them/iphone.html");
}
-->
</script>
```

*Do not forget to change http://url-to-send-them/iphone.html with YOUR mobile page!*

Answer (score -1):

We can super easy, bro!

Write THIS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "mobile.html";
}
//-->
</script>
```

I used it on my site. WE WORKING! 100% whit 000webhost.com and others!

*Do not forget to change mobile.html whit YOUR mobile page name*